# Can you customize a mysql_error duplicate error message?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, custom-error-pages

I'm getting a "Duplicate entry 'blah' for key 'username'" error message, but I would LOVE for it to read "This username already exists".

Is that possible? If so, where and how would I go about changing that?

I'm using PHP, MySQL and phpmyadmin.

Sorry for my noobishness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You... want to customize phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Where do you get this error message? In your application or in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query('... query that produces duplicate key error ...');
if ($result === FALSE) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1022) {
        die("Username already exists");
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

The error codes are documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/error-messages-server.html  and you can write your own custom error handler to output 'nicer' error messages if you so desire.